# Add enabled Computer to Active Directory OU

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2003

I am trying to programmatically add a computer to the Active Directory of my company.
I was searching the internet for so long now, but i couldn't find a solution.

My code:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=ou2example,OU=ou1example,DC=site,DC=company,DC=com");
dirEntry.Username = "username";
dirEntry.Password = "password";
DirectoryEntry newComputer = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + ComputerName, "computer");
newComputer.CommitChanges();
```

My problem:

The computer is added to the Active Directory. But it is flagged as disabled.

[image]

I tried to following to enable the computer:

```
newComputer.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x200;
```

But I get an DirectoryServicesCOMException --> The server can not complete the request.

or

```
newComputer.Properties["Enabled"].Value = true;
```

But I get an DirectoryServicesCOMException --> The requested operation does not satisfy at least one constraint that is for this object class condition.

Please note that the exceptions are translated from german to english!

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think two things can be wrong but it's been a long time since I did anything like this so I maybe wrong...

First of all, when do you set the `userAccountControl` flag? I seem to remember you should do this after the `CommitChanges` for the new entry. So like this:

```
DirectoryEntry newComputer =
    dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + ComputerName, "computer");
newComputer.CommitChanges();
newComputer.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x200;
newComputer.CommitChanges();
```

Second, can you try setting the [`UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT`](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm#UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT) flag (`0x1000`) instead of [`UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT`](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm#UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT) (`0x200`).

Can you also check whether the `sAMAccountType` of the entry is `SAM_MACHINE_ACCOUNT` (`0x30000001`). I think this should be automatic but doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I was setting the userAccountControl flag before committing changes.
When I set them afterwards and when I am using 0x1000 I don't get an exception but the computer is still disabled :(

Comment: There are certain restrictions to the value of UserAccountControl for newly created objects. I encountered similar issue when creating new user account with empty password. I.e., the server refused to create the user if the "Do not require password" flag was not set and password was not provided. I think you are hitting the same issue. Try to create a computer account manually, check the value and do a binary OR operation of that value with 0x200 to make sure you are not doing anything potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly one year later and also one year wiser, I know exactly what I was doing wrong.

So I want to share with you the correct way, even though I already selected an answer.

### Code

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP Path”);
DirectoryEntry newComputer = dirEntry.Children.Add(“CN=Hostname”, “computer”);
newComputer.Properties[“sAMAccountName”].Value = Hostname + “$”;
newComputer.Properties[“UserAccountControl”].Value = 0x1020;
newComputer.CommitChanges();
```

### Explanation

**sAMAccountName**

*Explanation found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/eec574c0-5421-4d7a-a806-a3c5af3d29bf/why-in-samaccount-name-of-computer-account-in-active-directory?forum=winserverDS)*

The sAMAccountName attribute of a computer object is the NetBIOS name of the computer with a trailing dollar sign, "$", appended. Besides flagging the object as a computer (which has class user), it also helps ensure uniqueness. The sAMAccountName value must be unique in the domain. Note, the Common Name of computer objects (the value of the cn attribute) does not have a trailing "$", but cn also does not uniquely identify the object in AD. The Common Name only needs to be unique in the OU or container.

Machine accounts are always given a trailing dollar sign "$" in their sAMAccountName attribute; this causes them to not be enumerated by certain APIs and therefore not displayed in certain user interfaces where one would expect to see only "user" accounts.

**UserAccountControl**

[image: UserAccountControl Flag Values]